# How to rename a groupby result coulmn in python

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a code, I want to change the name of "UC" column as "No.of RCA". Please help me in it.

here is the code

```
    agency.groupby(['Agency']).agg({
'UC':'count',
'Total number of children aged 9 months less to 15 years assessed in this RCA':'sum',
'Total number of children received TCV':'sum',
'nonvaccinated':'sum'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to rename the columns as required.

Use:

```
agency.groupby(['Agency']).agg({
'UC':'count',
'Total number of children aged 9 months less to 15 years assessed in this RCA':'sum',
'Total number of children received TCV':'sum',
'nonvaccinated':'sum'}).rename(columns={"UC": "No. of RCA"})
```

Answer (score 2):

For renaming column_name we use .rename function:

```
agency = agency.rename(columns={'UC': 'No.of RCA'})
```